# Is it possible to have a UIPanGesture and UISwipeGesture together?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a UIIMageView subclass and I am adding both a UIPanGestureRecognizer and a UISwipeGestureRecognizer as follows:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIPanGestureRecognizer * panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeUp:)];
swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[self addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeDown:)];
swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[self addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
```

but when I swipe up or down my selectors do not get called but the pan always does.

Any clarification would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: try to using this property of panGesture "minimumNumberOfTouches"
The minimum number of fingers that can be touching the view for this gesture to be recognized. set it to 2 and check whether swipe is recognized or not ?

Comment: Yes, that works, but then i need two fingers to do my pan so that is not really what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the swipe gesture will be recognized as a panGesture too.

What you need to do is set the delegate to a class that implement the method:

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

This will allow you to recognize the two gestures simultaneous, but need to be clear to you that always when your swipe is called your pan will called too.

[From apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate):

> This method is called when recognition of a gesture by either gestureRecognizer or otherGestureRecognizer would block the other gesture recognizer from recognizing its gesture. Note that returning YES is guaranteed to allow simultaneous recognition; returning NO, on the other hand, is not guaranteed to prevent simultaneous recognition because the other gesture recognizer's delegate may return YES.

Comment: I will try that.  I believe that will be ok, because if it is a pan, i check the region and if it is where i want the pan to be then I handle it, likewise for the swipe.

Comment: One thing, when I do what you propose, can I use my UIImageView class?  I would make that method in my UIImageView class and then do something  like [panGesture setDelegate:self] for each gesture?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can. and Yes for the second question too.

Comment: Great, I implemented what you suggested... it works great for me, thanks!!

Comment: @ggrana: Thanks for solving a problem that took me a couple of days to figure out. If I may add something: This line of code should be put in the right file.

I first placed it in the Delegate file itself but... naaaaaa didn't make it. So careful folks.