# MWFSlideNavigationViewController Not Working with Swipe Gesture Recognizer Created from the NIB File

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller

I'm using MWFSlideNavigationViewController Slide Navigation View Controller in the Up and Down directions only to reveal a secondary view.

I'd like to use left and right swipes for other things. It turns out UISwipeGestureRecognizer does not seem to work on the main view (the primary). I've created the Swipe Gesture Recognizer from the Nib file. On the contrary UITapGestureRecognizer works perfectly even though I've created in the same conditions.

So which tweaks should I do in order to be able to swipe left and right?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed:

It turned out I had to add the following lines to allow `Pan Gesture` (that was used in the original code) to work with `Swipe Gesture` that I wan't to add.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks to the following answers:

[UISwipeGestureRecognizer not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598505/uiswipegesturerecognizer-not-firing/13598573#comment27216991_13598573)

[Is it possible to have a UIPanGesture and UISwipeGesture together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907673/is-it-possible-to-have-a-uipangesture-and-uiswipegesture-together/9910624#comment27217113_9910624)